# program which asks for two numbers: One decimal (floating point) and one integer (whole number), first number (float) to the power of the second (int)

Tags: python

Give a decimal number: 5.5

Give an integer number: 3

5.5 to the power of 3 is approximately 166.

To be exact it is 166.38.

```
dec = float(input('Give a decimal number: '))
ger = input('Give an integer number: ')
z = dec**ger
print(dec,'to the power of',int,'is approximately',{0:.2f}.format(z))
print('To be exact it is',str(z)+".")
```

File "**tester**.python3", line 10

print(dec,'to the power of',int,'is approximately',{0:.2f}.format(z))

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: "To be exact it is 166.38." But 5.5^3 is exactly 166.375, isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format specification needs to be a string, and thus inside quotes:

```
print(dec,'to the power of',int,'is approximately',"{0:.2f}".format(z))
```

Comment: Not to mention that `ger` needs to be converted to an integer: `z = dec ** int(ger)`.

Comment: @Alexander Yes, but OP is clearly learning and ideally should come up with that on their own.